# create if statements blocks based on the value of an XML element

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

How can i create if statements blocks based on the value of id (XML element)

```
string filepath = Server.MapPath("XMLFile2.xml");

XmlDocument xdoc1 = new XmlDocument();
xdoc1.Load(filepath);

XmlNode root = xdoc1.DocumentElement;
XmlNode idNode = root.SelectSingleNode("/students/student/id");

   if (idNode.Value == 1.ToString()){my code}
```

im afraid that this code selects the first node in the file,,, or this there another way i can select the node based on its id value????

Comment: throw away that **OLD** `Xml Api`..`Use LINQ2XML`

Comment: well then, how can i do it in lINQ2SQL????

Comment: you should show us your `xml` and what `node` you want from your xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LINQ2XML`

```
XElement doc =XElement.Load(filepath);
var xpath = String.Format("//students/student/[id='{0}']", "1");
                                                            -
                                                            |->your ID value goes here
var StudentNodeWithID1= doc.XPathSelectElement(xpath);
//selects a single student node with id as 1 or would return NULL if there are no students with id as 1
```

**OR**

```
var StudentNodeWithID1= doc.Elements("student")
                           .Where(s => s.Element("id").Value == "1")
                           .SingleOrDefault();

StudentNodeWithID1.Element("id");//id node
StudentNodeWithID1.Element("id").Value;//id value
```

Comment: StudentNodeWithID1.Element("first_name").Value = TextBox_firstname.Text;
doesnt work after the "var" statement......

Comment: <students>
  <student>
    <id>1</id>
    <first_name>ahmad</first_name>
    <last_name>hani</last_name>
    <DOB>ahmad</DOB>
    <class>hani</class>
    <section>ahmad</section>
    <telephone>hani</telephone>
  </student>
</students>

Comment: @user1750680 `doc.ToString()` gives you the `xml`..any changes made through `linq2xml` should be atleast reflected in that..without your code I cannot help you...

Answer (score 3):

Replace your this code

**Previous code**

```
XmlNode idNode = root.SelectSingleNode("/students/student/id");
```

**New code**

```
XmlNode idNode = root.SelectSingleNode("//students/student/id");
```

And ya mostly if you want to search node base on the value of id than use following.

```
XmlNode idNode = root.SelectSingleNode("//students/student/[id='"+<YOUR id>+"']");
```

It will work...